# Random названия блока

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

```
<div id=tat onclick="toggle('content1','j1')">
<script>
    function toggle(id1,id2) {
    var el1 = document.getElementById(id1);
        el1.style.display = (el1.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
        var el2 = document.getElementById(id2);
        el2.style.display = (el2.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
    }
</script>
<div id=j1 style="display:none;">
</div>
</div>
```

Вот он код.
Как сделать, чтобы наверху, вместо j1 делался j и случайное число до семи.. тоесть j1 или j2 или j5 и тд...

То есть чтобы при клике на блок ¨tat¨ чтобы появлялся блок с названием j и рандомным номером до семи. 
и чтобы название этого блока , например он стал j5, чтобы именно это новое название писалось в конец моего кода, там где сейчас стоит `j1 style="display:` и тд.. 
и с блоком `content1` то же самое, какой у j станет число, такое же чтоб было и у `content`.

Спасибо.

Comment: да вы просто не используйте onclick в разметке, или хотя-бы this передавайте, для ссылки на тот объект что кликнули... и ещё, что за странная идея скрипт внутрь блока складывать ? лучше скажите что вы пытаетесь сделать, скорее всего вы выбрали неверный путь.

Comment: Я хотел, чтобы при нажатии на блок tat, появлялся блок j1 и сбоку появлялся блок content1 одновременно. Как-то с этим разобрался и всё заработало. Но мне нужно немного другое.. чтобы блок был не именно j1, а рандомно какой-то из семи.. j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6 или j7. И какой блок выберется рандомно, такой-же content должен показываться одновременно. Таких блоков tat у меня несколько..По сути они квадратики.. как перевёрнутые карты.

Comment: при клике на одну карту, должен появляться блок этот (j).. типо что скрывалось за этой картой.. и сбоку одновременно контент - описывающий карту.. если можете дать совет, то пож-ста дайте его в виде кода, а не просто команд.. я не знаю js.. знаю дофига чего другого, изучением js займусь скоро.. но сейчас нету времени... помогите.. это не должно быть чем-то сложным.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rHtWh/ скорее всего не работает с ie<10 и может быть вообще в ie, если надо кроссбраузерно  делайте на jquery,

Comment: @turguni лучше выучите что нибудь, или наймите кодера/препода

Comment: Уф, что не спросишь.. на любом форуме .. на любую тему.. всегда ответ, или оскорбления, или иди найми специалиста.. Спасибо..

Comment: потому-что ваши вопросы примитивны, отвечать на них неинтересно, вы сами не до конца понимаете чего хотите , а так-же вы ничего не вынесете кроме как скопипастить код. а работать над не своей идеей бесплатно очень странная затея.

Answer (score 1):

[Удобный метод рандом](http://javascript.ru/Math.random)

ps: описание неоднозначное, остается только догадываться, [что вам нужно](http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/7k5ue/28/), 
если для вас это уже глубокое знание js, то

- 1 - изучите код внимательно + отладчик,
- 2 - пройдите любой курс, [хоть этот](http://learn.javascript.ru/intro).

Comment: Ну как в моём случае это применить? уже 2 ночи не сплю, всегда сам до всего допираю, но тут чо-то слишком долго мучаюсь.. подскажите, ребят, Вам жеж не сложно)